# Отменить слияние мастера с моей веткой

Tags: git, bitbucket, source-tree

Работаю с Source-tree. 
У меня есть своя ветка с которой я работаю. 
По ошибке я зашел в мастер и от туда сделал слияние с моей веткой, после зашел в свою ветку, и сделал pull, и таким образом все что было в мастере залилось в мою локальную копию. 
Теперь в моей локальной версии, сайт работает не так как до этого.
Подскажите как можно отменить последнее слияние мастера с моей веткой. 
Или как можно вернуться до слияния мастера с моей веткой, и вернуть состояние сайта в прежнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать ресетом, зная хэш коммита, на который вы хотите откатиться:

```
git reset --hard 56e05fced
```

Пользуйтесь с осторожностью, [reset](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-reset)